# Not receiving full data

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have the following socket code in C.  I am trying to receive 70 bytes of data on each cycle. However, I am getting only 4 bytes of data. The full data is something like this (in hex):

```
4D43475000856308000004B2DE1F04009E00200100000000696CF7AB002F1A00000000
000000325C000402069BFDE70857E22502F41C000036000000DF0B0932100B09DC0719
```

What is the problem? I have tried to research many StackOverflow answers, but with no help.

The code is as below:

```
void doprocessing (int sock);

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n, pid;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 14064;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Now start listening for the clients, here
     * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
     * for the incoming connection
    */

    listen(sockfd,5000);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while (1) {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Create child process */
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            /* This is the client process */
            close(sockfd);
            doprocessing(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            close(newsockfd);
        }

    } /* end of while */
}

void doprocessing (int sock) 
{
    int n,i;
    unsigned int *buffer = malloc(1024);

    n = read(sock,buffer,1023);

    if (n < 0) {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Here is the message: %.4x\n",*buffer);

    n = write(sock,"MCGP",18);

    if (n < 0) {
       perror("ERROR writing to socket");
       exit(1);
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: The third argument to `recv()` is just the maximum that it can return, it can return less. You need to call it in a loop until you get everything you want.

Comment: `clilen` should be `socklen_t` not `int`.

Comment: How do you know you're not getting the whole thing? `%.4x` just prints a single `int`, not the whole message.

Comment: @Barmar Please explain why it should no work

Comment: Reading from a socket does not necessarily return the number of bytes requested, but might return few, for a blocking socket down to just one byte per call. The code needs to loop around `read()`/`recv()` counting until all data expected had been read. Read the man page carefully.

Comment: It's just what `%x` is defined to do. If you want to print the whole `buffer` array, you need to call it in a loop for each `buffer[i]`.

Comment: Also, since `buffer` contains integers, the size you should read is `1024*sizeof(int)`, not just `1024`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a number of bugs in your code:

1. `clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);` needs to be moved inside of the `while` loop above the `accept()` call.
2. `unsigned int *buffer` should be `unsigned char *buffer` instead.
3. Why are you reading 1023 bytes when you are only expecting 70 bytes?
4. You need to call `read()` in a loop until you actually receive all of the bytes you are expecting. `read()` can return fewer bytes than requested.  TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of message boundaries, the read will return whatever bytes are currently available, so it will return *at least* 1 byte *up to* the requested number of bytes.
5. Your `printf()` call is only outputting the first 4 bytes of `buffer`, it is not outputting the full content of `buffer`.  The return value of `read()` tells you how many bytes were actually received.  Loop through the `buffer` outputting each byte individually.
6. `write(sock,"MCGP",18)` is a buffer overflow, since you are only passing 5 bytes (4 characters and the null terminator) but are telling it to send 18 bytes instead.

Try this instead:

```
void doprocessing (int sock);

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;
    int pid;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("ERROR creating socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 14064;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Now start listening for the clients, here
     * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
     * for the incoming connection
    */

    if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Create child process */
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            /* This is the client process */
            close(sockfd);
            doprocessing(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            close(newsockfd);
        }

    } /* end of while */
}

void doprocessing (int sock) 
{
    int n, i;
    unsigned char buffer[70], *p = buffer;
    size_t len = 70;

    do {
        n = read(sock, p, len);
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("ERROR reading from socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            perror("DISCONNECTED unexpectedly");
            exit(1);
        }

        p += n;
        len -= n;
    }
    while (len > 0);

    printf("Here is the message: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
        printf("%.02x", buffer[i]);
    printf("\n");

    n = write(sock, "MCGP", 4);
    if (n < 0) {
       perror("ERROR writing to socket");
       exit(1);
    }
}
```